# Need help to get Access Token

Tags: c#, facebook, c#-4.0

Here, I am using user id generated by facebook in place of appid . Am I correct here??
As I wanted to get access token with the help of user name and password for my application designed in windows forms. I am using below code to fetch it. Please, give me any better solution to fetch access token.

```
        string appId = userid.ToString(); 
        string[] extendedPermissions = new[] { "publish_stream", "offline_access" }; 
        var oauth = new FacebookOAuthClient { ClientId = appId };
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
        { "response_type", "token" },  { "display", "popup" } };
        if (extendedPermissions != null && extendedPermissions.Length > 0) 
        { 
            var scope = new StringBuilder(); 
            scope.Append(string.Join(",", extendedPermissions));
            parameters["scope"] = scope.ToString(); 
        }
        var loginUrl = oauth.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
        wbTestWindow.Navigate(loginUrl);

        // this webBrowser's related navigated function
        private void wbTestWindow_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
        FacebookOAuthResult result; 
        if (FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(e.Url, out result)) 
        { 
            if (result.IsSuccess) 
            { 
                var accesstoken = result.AccessToken;
            } 
            else
            { 
                var errorDescription = result.ErrorDescription; 
                var errorReason = result.ErrorReason; 
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @NeilKnight I am getting result as null !!